# Sublime text 2 php highlighting

Tags: javascript, php, css, sublimetext2

How to highlight only php code in Sublime Text 2?

At the moment I use this in my theme:

```
<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Embedded source</string>
    <key>scope</key>
    <string>text source</string>
    <key>settings</key>
    <dict>
        <key>background</key>
        <string>#4d363c</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

works but also it's highlighting javascript and stylesheets.. I want only the php code like Notepad++ does http://s21.postimg.org/jk5ctcwhj/php_highlighting.jpg

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *almost* have it. Instead of your scope being `text source`, just set it to `text source.php` and you'll be all set. This avoids other languages like `source.js`, `source.css`, etc.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if it works for `Sublime Text 2` (I am currently using `Sublime Text 3`), neither if it works as you expect, but it might worth a try (or at least help anyone else interested in something similar):

`Ctrl` + `Shift` + `P` opens the `Tools` > `Command Palette` option.

Then, type `ssphp` and hit enter.

After these steps, the `Set Syntax: PHP` action will be applied.

<sub>**Note:** If you want to set the syntax to something different from php, type `ss` (to filter for all `Set Syntax`es actions, and then type the language you want.</sub>

Comment: I believe he is looking for inline PHP highlighting (i.e. within an HTML document), not syntax highlighting for the entire document.

Comment: @Jason Yes, you are correct, thank you for pointing this out. But it is the closer I can help and that's why I've wrote: `I'm not sure if it works as you expect, but it might worth a try (or at least help anyone else interested in something similar)`.